# Strategy for a Positive Return Slot Machine

Tags: probability, optimization

**Problem Statement**

You're given a positive return slot machine that takes in a real number's worth of money and either doubles it or eats it.`P(Win) = X` and `P(Lose) = 1 - P(Win)` where `0.5 < X <= 1`. You start with exactly 1 dollar. What's your strategy to make the most money possible in the shortest number of transactions without losing all your money?

**Background**

I've been doing some review and remembered a scenario posed by my probability professor to get everyone engaged in the course. However, it turns out that we never answered the question by the end of the quarter! At a glance it seems like an optimization problem... maxing the money made and minimizing the transaction count, but there's seems to be a lot of variables involved here:

- Target money to be made
- Transaction count
- The probability to win (if its 1, we just all in every time)
- An allowed risk to lose all your money

I'm not sure where to start and I'm curious about how a problem like this even gets set up. I can imagine a recursive expected value equation somewhere but don't know how I would incorporate the number of transactions. What happens when the target money is infinite? What if we have a maximum number of allowed transactions? Is there a single solution that addresses all these different cases?

Comment: Other variables to include are amount of money you start with and allowed bet amounts. You said "real numbers", but if bets can be any real number, then you never lose all of your money as long as you don't bet it all, AND you can still keep betting forever by betting smaller and smaller amounts.

Comment: This (Math) problem is faced by professional sports bettors, who are (typically) very risk averse.  The typical approach is to not bet more than $3\%$ of your sports betting bankroll, with the exception of (manual) parleys.  That is, if Bet-1 wins, and Bet-2 seems to be above-average-promising, let it ride instead of keeping the bet size at $3\%$.  The entire issue is very tricky.